# Unable to click "Create an account" button on Firefox browser by robot framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

Unable to click "Create an account" button on firefox browser 
(version:59.03 & 60, geckodriver-v0.20.0 & v0.20.1 for win64) 
by robot framework on RIDE from [link](http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account):

Code Like on RIDE

```
Open Browser    http://automationpractice.com   firefox     
Click Link  class=login                 
Wait Until Element Is Visible   xpath://input[@name='back']/following-sibling::button[@name='SubmitCreate'] None    None   
Click Button    xpath://input[@name='back']/followingsibling::button[@name='SubmitCreate']
```

XPath(//button[@type='submit' and @name='SubmitCreate']) is working and test cases is Pass. But the browser is not able to click on Create an account button. 
More details may be seen from the [link](https://www.screencast.com/t/uHoSRz5P6UZ). I already passed 3 days did not get a solution. Could yoy please take a look.

Comment: What does "not able to" mean? Do you get an error? If so, what error? If you don't get an error, what happens? Does it click the wrong button? Does it say it clicked the button but nothing happened?

Comment: 1. Firefox driver is not able to click on “Create an account” button on by robot framework RIDE from http://automationpractice.com/index.php?controller=authentication&back=my-account.
2. I did not get an error.
3&4. It did not click on the button but test case is a pass.
4. More detail you can find at  link : https://www.screencast.com/t/uHoSRz5P6UZ

Comment: To be clear, "not able" means that robot reports that it clicked on the button, but nothing happened? You say your test passed, so why is this a problem? Shouldn't your test be doing something after the click to verify that the click worked, such as checking that it's on a new page or an item was selected, or whatever the click is supposed to do?

Comment: After clicking on "Create an account" button, A error message "Invalid email address." should display. I am not sure why my test case is passed without clicking on "Create an account" button. After running script robot did not click on "Create an account" button. I just wanted to click on "Create an account" button, and then A error message "Invalid email address." should display. Thanks.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, Could you please take a look my answer and vote me.

Answer (score 0):

Some browser version is unable to click some button action. After 3 days later, I got the solution. It works on Mozilla Firefox version 52 and Gecko driver version 0.18.0.Thanks to all.